# Use Ordinance Survey Map Tiles in React Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm working on a project which requires detailed maps of rural areas.  I'm currently using the default leaflet map as a placeholder but I'd really like to start using the Ordinance Survey (OS) map API.  I've been able to get the OS map tiles to render in base Leaflet but so far I haven't been able to get them to display in a React component.

The example code I'd like to 'reactify' can be found here: https://labs.os.uk/public/os-data-hub-examples/os-maps-api/wmts-27700-basic-map#leaflet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>OS Maps API | Basic Map WMTS (EPSG:27700) | Leaflet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://labs.os.uk/public/os-api-branding/v0.3.1/os-api-branding.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://labs.os.uk/public/os-api-branding/v0.3.1/os-api-branding.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.7.0/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4leaflet/1.0.2/proj4leaflet.min.js"></script>
<script>

    const apiKey = 'INSERT_API_KEY_HERE';

    // Setup the EPSG:27700 (British National Grid) projection.
    const crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:27700', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs', {
        resolutions: [ 896.0, 448.0, 224.0, 112.0, 56.0, 28.0, 14.0, 7.0, 3.5, 1.75 ],
        origin: [ -238375.0, 1376256.0 ]
    });

    // Transform coordinates.
    const transformCoords = function(arr) {
        return proj4('EPSG:27700', 'EPSG:4326', arr).reverse();
    };

    // Define parameters object.
    const params = {
        key: apiKey,
        service: 'WMTS',
        request: 'GetTile',
        version: '2.0.0',
        height: 256,
        width: 256,
        outputFormat: 'image/png',
        style: 'default',
        layer: 'Leisure_27700',
        tileMatrixSet: 'EPSG:27700',
        tileMatrix: '{z}',
        tileRow: '{y}',
        tileCol: '{x}'
    };

    // Construct query string parameters from object.
    const queryString = Object.keys(params).map(function(key) {
        return key + '=' + params[key];
    }).join('&');

    // Initialize the map.
    const mapOptions = {
        crs: crs,
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 9,
        center: transformCoords([ 337297, 503695 ]),
        zoom: 7,
        maxBounds: [
            transformCoords([ -238375.0, 0.0 ]),
            transformCoords([ 900000.0, 1376256.0 ])
        ],
        attributionControl: false
    };

    const map = L.map('map', mapOptions);

    // Load and display WMTS tile layer on the map.
    const basemap = L.tileLayer('https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/wmts?' + queryString).addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We’re going to need to see your attempt at rewriting this in React.

Comment: I don't want to share my API key